# How do I locate a select option element in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have the following html code below: How do I locate and click any of the options e.g 'verve'?

```
<div id="cardsSelectList">
<select id="cardtype" class="selinput" tabindex="1" onchange="webpay.ProcessCardTypeSelection($(this).val())" name="cardtype">
<option value="-1">- Select your card type -</option>
<option value="1|1|1|Card Number|0|Card PIN|1|0|||0|0">Verve\u2122</option>
<option value="1|1|1|Card Number|0|Card PIN|1|0|||0|0">MasterCard\u2122 Naira Debit</option>
<option value="1|0|1|Card Number|0|Card PIN|0|0|||0|0">Visa</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Which selenium language bindings are you using?

Comment: See the below video may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfYj3DYnN0c

Answer (score 0):

Use `Select` class

```
@FindBy(id="cardtype")
private WebElement selectElement;
Select select = new Select(selectElement);
select.selectByValue("1|1|1|Card Number|0|Card PIN|1|0|||0|0");
```

You also have option to select byt `text, index etc`. refer to [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)

**written in java and refer to java. But the api is fairly similar for any other bindings**